# Angular: memory-leak after concurrent downloads?

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, download, observable

I'm developing an Angular app and I created a download page like this:

[image]

If I have a look at Chrome task manager I see that the process related to my app keeps about 130 MB of memory.

Then, users can launch simultaneous downloads clicking on every download button (the total files size is 266 MB):

[image]

Now, if I check again the task manager I see that the memory usage growns and when all downloads are finished its peak is about 650 MB.
I noticed a weird thing: the final usage of the memory seems to be the total of the following formula:

**initial memory usage + 2 * total files size = final memory usage**

**130 MB + 2 * 266 MB = 130 MB + 532 MB = 662 MB = ~650 MB.**

If i try to use the Chrome garbage collector it cuts off about 30 MB, but I still have the app that has 620 MB as memory usage.
So, how can I fix this behaviour? Can you see anything wrong with my code?
(I have tried to use `unsubscribe` on Component's `ngOnDestroy`, but it didn't work)

Here is the function that is called when I click on the download button of a file (from a download page):

```
getFile(file: any): void {
    this.fileDownloadService.downloadFile(file).subscribe(
        (fileinfo: SispFile) => {
            file.downloading = true;
        },
        (err: any) => {
            file.downloading = false;
            console.log('errore', err);
        },
        () => {
            file.downloading = false;
            console.log('completated');
        });
}
```

Here is the `downloadFile` function in the `FileDownloadService`, called by `getFile`:

```
downloadFile(file: SispFile): Observable<any> {
    let conf: any = {};
    conf.totalChunks = Math.max(Math.ceil(file.size / this.chunkSizeDownload), 1);
    conf.mime = file.extension;
    conf.currentChunk = 0;
    conf.byteDownloaded = 0;
    conf.chunkSizeDownload = this.chunkSizeDownload;
    conf.chunkBlobs = [];
    conf.finalBlob = null;

    file.progress = 0;

    return new Observable(observer => {
        observer.next(file);
        this.addChunk(file, observer, conf);
    })
}

addChunk(file: SispFile, observer: any, conf: any) {
    if (conf.currentChunk == conf.totalChunks) {
        observer.complete();
        conf.finalBlob = new Blob(conf.chunkBlobs, {type: conf.mime});

        let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(conf.finalBlob);
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = fileURL;
        a.download = file.name;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
    } else {
        this.docService.downloadFile(file, conf.chunkSizeDownload, conf.byteDownloaded)
            .then(response => {
                let typedArray = this.createBlob(response['_body'], conf.mime);
                conf.chunkBlobs[conf.currentChunk] = typedArray;
                conf.currentChunk++;
                conf.byteDownloaded = conf.currentChunk * conf.chunkSizeDownload;
                if (conf.Downloaded + this.chunkSizeDownload > file.size) {
                    conf.chunkSizeDownload = file.size - conf.Downloaded + 1;
                }

                let progress = Math.round((conf.currentChunk * 100) / conf.totalChunks);
                file.progress = progress;
                observer.next(file);
                this.addChunk(file, observer, conf);
            })
            .catch((error: ErrorMessage) => {
                observer.error(error);
                console.log('Errore server: ' + error);
            });
    }
}
```

And here is the final call to back-end endpoint in the `DocService`:

```
downloadFile(file: SispFile, length: number, offset: number) {
    let url = Util.format(this.downloadFileUrl, {id: file.id});
    let body: any = { "downloadMode": "PAYLOAD", "fileId": file.id, "length": length, "offset": offset };
    return this.http.post(url, body)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            return response;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that Angular has this [`Testability`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Testability-class.html) class. It's definition:

> The Testability service provides testing hooks that can be accessed
>   from the browser and by services such as Protractor. Each bootstrapped
>   Angular application on the page will have an instance of Testability.

And you can access *A global registry of Testability instances for specific elements* through [`TestabilityRegistry`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/TestabilityRegistry-class.html).

As we can see in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13725), destroying a component doesn't free browser's memory because Testability API doesn't release it's references.

So, maybe, by cleaning up the TestabilityRegistry on destroy could help you get rid of those references that summed up are causing your 620MB memory leaks.

Here is [the fix](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/14819) that I have found!

I hope this is of help for fixing your issue, or at least I hope I could manage to give you a different point of view or a new field of research!

**Update:**

From what I have saw, in order to clean `TestabilityRegistry`:

In **modules/@angular/core/src/testability/testability.ts**:

```
destroy(): void {
  this._applications.clear();
  testabilityGetter.onDestroy();
}
```

This would be the **destroy** method.

In **modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.ts**:

```
this._injector.get(TestabilityRegistry).destroy();
```

We invoke the destroy method.

In **modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/testability.ts**:

```
onDestroy(): void {
   delete global.getAngularTestability;
   delete global.getAllAngularTestabilities;
   delete global.getAllAngularRootElements;
   delete global.frameworkStabilizers;
}
```

When destroying we make sure that we are deleting the testability instances.

**Take a look to [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/14819/commits/b9f6585b162a0ab2e03bfa521bbc123d94a64e62).** It shows you how to clean up TestabilityRegistry.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Then, what should I do? I see that fix isn't merged to Angular master repository.

Comment: @smartmouse I believe you could initially fork it and test if it fixes your problem. Maybe you could tweak forked repository until it suits your need.

Comment: If I try to fork, then do you know how to clean up `TestabilityRegistry`?

Comment: @smartmouse I have updated my answer. I believe you should try out what's on that commit. It seems that can work as a good temporary fix.

Comment: I did see that commit, I misunderstood your answer, then there is no need to do anything in my components if I apply this fix to my angular... Now I'm trying to apply those changes to my repository...

Comment: @smartmouse Nice! :D Let me know how it goes! Hope it solves your leaking issue!

Comment: I did tried to use the fix, but it don't solve my issue. Thank you anyway for your support. (Here is my modified Angular: http://www.filedropper.com/angularfixed)